# Cannot build JMVC application because of socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, socket.io, javascriptmvc

I have an application, which uses socket.io, and when I try to build the app, it says:

```
failed to open file  file:/socket.io/socket.io.js   JavaException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /socket.io/socket.io.js (No such file or directory)
```

I use node.js as a back-end, so I do `steal('/socket.io/socket.io.js')` on the client side. I am guessing `steal/buildjs`, which I'm using, is trying to get socket.io.js into a production.js. How can I exclude it from the build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't put socket.io.js into your build. It has to be included from your nodejs server via it's own script tag. Put the tag in your app's HTML file.

Alternatively, you can load it dynamically like this:

```
$.getScript('//yoursocketio.server/socket.io/socket.io.js',function() {
  io.connect('yoursocketio.server').etc();
});
```

But you should never steal it.

Comment: Agreed. Stealing compressed JS causes major headaches when building.